# Change the button color, icon and text in Angular2

Tags: angular

I want to change the color, icon and text of the button based on boolean value when I am clicking on the button. Means if I will click on active button it should change to deactive and color should change from btn-suceess to btn-danger and icon from fa-ban to fa-check.

```
<button [hidden]= "user.active" [ngClass]="{ 'btn-danger': user.active, 'btn-success': !user.active}" (click) ="click()">
  <i [ngClass]="{'fa-ban': user.active, 'fa-check': !user.active}" class="fa"> </i>
    {{ text }}
</button>
```

Then in .ts file  I have two method and I have added one method like this:

```
deactivate(user){
  this.user.active = true;
  this.userService.userStatus(this.user).subscribe(
    user => {
      console.log(user);
     },
    err => {
     console.log('err:', err);
    }
  );
  };

activate(user){
 this.user.active = false;
 this.userService.userStatus(this.user).subscribe(
  user => {
     console.log(user);
  },
  err => {
    console.log('err:', err);
  }
  );
};

click() {
  if (this.user.active) {
      this.user.active = false;
      this.text = "Active";
  } else {
      this.user.active = true;
      this.text = "Deactive";
   }
}
```

Now I am able to change the text only but now the value is not getting updated in db and as well as icon and button color is not getting changed.

Answer (score 2):

You're going about it the wrong way. Your template should only contain that button once. It should be something like this:

```
<button [ngClass]="{'btn-danger':user.active, 'btn-success':!user.active}"
        (click)="click()">
  <i [ngClass]="{'fa-ban':user.active, 'fa-check':!user.active}" class="fa"> </i>
  {{text}}
</button>
```

And the component something like this:

```
export class MyComponent {
    user = { active: true };
    text = "Deactive";

    click() {
        if (this.user.active) {
            this.user.active = false;
            this.text = "Active";
        } else {
            this.user.active = true;
            this.text = "Deactive";
        }
    }
```

Note that I'm not using $event.target to access the DOM element directly. When using Angular, try to avoid that. My example shows you how to change the text and class of both the button and the icon using Angular.

Let me know how this works out for you.

**EDIT due to updated OP:**

I've created a Plunker with a working example. I had to remove the [disabled] on the button, because apparently that prevents the (click) event from being emitted when the button is disabled (makes sense).
But it still shows nicely, how to change the colors and text in an Angular way:

https://plnkr.co/edit/VxxoUeSHrP0I8lyMiVNK

Just click the link and hit the black "Run" button in the top bar.

Comment: thanks, I have changed the code as you said, but not getting the output. I have edited my posts.

Comment: @AmitKumar Did you get it working with my Plunker example? If so, then please accept my answer.

Answer (score 1):

in ts file add variable for check it

```
clickActive:Boolean = false;
```

in html

```
<button [hidden]= "user.active == false" 
[ngClass]="(state == true) ? 'btn-success':'btn-danger'"
(click) ="activation(user, $event.target, 'Deactive')">
  <i [ngClass]="(state == true) ? 'fa fa-ban':'fa fa-check'"> </i>
   Active
</button>
```

Don't forget to change state while click button

```
this.clickActive = !this.clickActive;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using bootstrap, why don't you just use bootstrap button toggle instead of reinventing the wheel?

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/